useMutation dependent on useQuery isError
I have a useQuery hook that takes an id, queries a database and returns two possible responses. Either it finds a row and returns it with HTTP status 200 or it doesn't and returns a HTTP status 404.
If a 404 is returned, the useQuery's isError is true. I check for isError and check for the status code for a 404. If all of that is true I want to call the mutate function.
I'm using @tanstack/react-query v5
This is what I have tried. These are all in different files.
This is the useQuery
const getUser = async (cnum: string) => {
  const { data } = await api.get<UserInfo>(`/users/get/${cnum}`);
  return data;
};

export const useGetUserQuery = () => {
  const auth = useAuth();
  const cnum = auth.user?.profile.uid as string;

  return useQuery({
    queryKey: ['user', 'get', cnum],
    queryFn: () => getUser(cnum),
    enabled: !!auth && !!cnum,
    staleTime: Infinity,
  });
};

This is the useMutation
const createUser = async (user: NewUser) => {
  const { data } = await api.post<UserInfo>(`/users/create`, user);
  return data;
};

export const useCreateUserMutation = () => {
  const queryClient = useQueryClient();
  const auth = useAuth();
  const user: NewUser = {
       // properties here
  }

  return useMutation({
    mutationKey: ['user', 'create', user],
    mutationFn: () => {
      return createUser(user);
    },
    onSuccess: async (data) => {
      await queryClient.invalidateQueries(
        {
          queryKey: ['user', 'get', data.cnum],
          refetchType: 'all', //using 'all' since I understand that the query won't be active since it is in error state, I could be wrong.
        },
      );
    },
  });
};

In App.tsx I was doing the following:
function App() {
const userInfo = useGetUserQuery();
const createUser = useCreateUserMutation();


if (userInfo.isSuccess) {
    sessionStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(userInfo.data));
  }

if (userInfo.isError) {
    const submit = async () => {
      try {
        await createUser.mutateAsync();
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('error', e);
      }
    };
    void submit();
  }

return (
  ...
)
}

I was then expecting that upon successful mutation, the previous useQuery would get invalidated and refetched, which would then (hopefully) return the newly created user.
Not sure if maybe I can directly set the data of the useQuery upon mutation success.
What I got seemed to be an infinite loop, where the mutate function was called repeatedly
